# Added custom customer attribute with patch script but it gives an error

Tags: custom, customer-attribute, eav-attributes, patch-data

I added a custom attribute to my customer with a data patch script. The attribute is added in the database tables but when I try to register a new customer I get this error:

main.CRITICAL: Exception message: Missing required argument $options of Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Config.

Did I do something wrong? and how to fix it?

This is my data patch script:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace OSP\SubUsers\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchRevertableInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetup;

/**
 */
class AddDebtorId  implements DataPatchInterface,  PatchRevertableInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;
    /**
     * @var CustomerSetup
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
    ) {
        /**
         * If before, we pass $setup as argument in install/upgrade function, from now we start
         * inject it with DI. If you want to use setup, you can inject it, with the same way as here
         */
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(  \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'debtor_id', [
            'type' => 'int',
            'input' => 'select',
            'label' => 'Debtor ID',
            'backend' => '',
            'source' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'required' => false,
            'default' => 0,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'system' => false,
            'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
            'is_used_in_grid' => true,
            'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
            'is_searchable_in_grid' => true,
            'position' => 300
        ]);


        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'debtor_id');
    $attribute->addData(
            [
                'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_checkout','adminhtml_customer','customer_account_edit','customer_account_create']
            ]);
        $attribute->save();
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [

        ];
    }

    public function revert()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $customerSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'debtor_id');

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        /**
         * This internal Magento method, that means that some patches with time can change their names,
         * but changing name should not affect installation process, that's why if we will change name of the patch
         * we will add alias here
         */
        return [];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have created an attribute of type "select" you need to set a source for the options.

'source' => \OSP\SubUsers\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Options::class

You source file can be like this.

```
<?php
namespace OSP\SubUsers\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource;

class Options extends AbstractSource
{
    /**
     * Retrieve All options
     *
     * @return array[]
     */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        if (null === $this->_options) {
            $this->_options = [
                ['label' => __('Option 1'), 'value' => 0],
                ['label' => __('Option 2'), 'value' => 1],
                ['label' => __('Option 3'), 'value' => 2],
                ['label' => __('Option 4'), 'value' => 4],
            ];
        }
        return $this->_options;
    }
}
```

If you just want the ID to be display you can set the input to text.